# Relative path not working for log file in Grails

Tags: grails, grails-2.0

I am trying to give relative path of my custom log file. But it not working, and if I give from complete path it working fine.

My code is like this:

```
log4j = {
    appenders {
        //  append new appenders of your own and add log level and packages/files like to add.
        rollingFile name: "myAppender",
                    maxFileSize: 1024,
                    file: "C:/GrailsWS/BaseGrails/target/basegrails.log"    // WORKING
                                          //"basegrails.log"   // NOT WORKING
                                          //"/target/basegrails.log"   //  NOT WORKING

        /*console name: "myAppender",
                layout: pattern(conversionPattern: "%c{2} %m%n")*/
    }
    debug myAppender: 'com.nagarro.base.grails.EmployeeController'
}
```

I tried above ways, but it not working.

Comment: you need to see this ? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21792100/grails-external-configuration-file and let me know further assitant you need how to put this into use

Answer (score 0):

to write logs in logs dir of tomcat/jetty or in project-root if launched with run-app I use this (if it helps):

```
String logName = “myapp.log"
String logDirectory
// getting tomcat dir
logDirectory = System.getProperty('catalina.base') ? "${System.getProperty('catalina.base')}/logs/" : ''
// getting jetty dir
if (System.getProperty('jetty.home') != null) {
    logDirectory = System.getProperty('jetty.home') ? "${System.getProperty('jetty.home')}/logs/" : ''
}

println("CONFIG:Writing log ${logName} in dir:" + logDirectory)

// log4j configuration
log4j = {

    appenders {
        appender new DailyRollingFileAppender(
                name: 'file', datePattern: "'.'yyyy-MM-dd",
                file: logDirectory + logName
        )}
...
```